# Labview filling an array with data

Tags: labview

I have code which generates an amount of data continuously and I'd like to store generated data in a 1-dimensional array.

How do I do this in LabVIEW?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the array to transfer data from your data acquisition to another location? If you know how many elements are in the array, you should first initialize the array to that size. Then you can place data in the array by using "Replace Array Subset". This way you're not continuously allocating memory. This also assumes that you're moving that data out of the array prior to the next instrument read.[image]

Comment: Hi Ryan Thanks for your reply. I'm basically acquiring data continously, and I'd like to put it into an array form. I think I've worked it out with the Collector Express VI, but I'd like a simpler solution. It's like every second or so, I get a data point, and I want to put it as nr. 1, 2, 3, ... in an array. That sounds very basic to me, but I'm also new in labview.

Comment: Hi Jens, any chance you could post a screen shot? Typically when acquiring data continuously, you'll need to move the data away from the acquisition loop/process to another loop/process to do work on it. LabVIEW ships with sample projects that might be helpful for this. You can find these by going to File >> Create Project... then look for the example project called "Continuous Measurement an Logging". Your acquisition code will go in the Acquisition Message Loop.vi. Your processing loop would go in Logging Message Loop.vi (for data logging) or in a new similar VI.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is better to use while loop (if you know the exact number of data you can use For Loop as well, giving an N terminal defined number of iterations). Simply connect your generated data wire to the border of the while loop, right click it and choose Tunnel Mode:Indexing and you will get and array.

Comment: I think I tried the while loop last time I was in the lab, and labview broke down, but it should work, so I'll test it again tomorrow. Otherwise I'll have to go with the Collector Express VI. Thanks!